# Connecting to personal wifi on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, wireless, internet, netplan

I have followed a number of tutorials recommending different things with netplan for connecting to the internet. None of them have worked. Should i be trying to connect with something else? or should netplan work and i have done something wrong?
If you know of some tutorial i can follow that would help that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What tutorials specificaly did you follow, what didn't work, what was the output?  Netplan is certainly the recommended interface to use on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Could you please show the netplan config from /etc/netplan/*.yaml which is not working for you?

Comment: for me systemctl status netplan-wpa-wlp3s0.service reported that /sbin/wpa_sipplicant cant be found. i will try to install it through eth and try again :(

Answer (score 4):

If Netplan doesn't work, one alternative (there might be others) is to connect up to the wireless LAN the old-fashioned way using `wpa_supplicant`:

Note: All these commands should be run as root or with sudo:

First, check which interfaces you are working with:

```
ip link
```

You should see an interface beginning with "wlan" or "wlp" - for example: `wlan0` or `wlp2s0`. Bring this interface up:

```
ip link set <interface> up
```

For example, if `wlp2s0` is the interface:

```
ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

Create the `wpa_supplicant` configuration file with the following command (assuming your network is WPA-PSK encrypted):

```
wpa_passphrase "<SSID>" "<Password>" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

For example:

```
wpa_passphrase "MyHomeNetwork" "abcd1234" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Start wpa_supplicant in the background:

```
wpa_supplicant -Bc /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i <interface>
```

Finally, if you are using a DHCP connection, start `dhclient`:

```
dhclient <interface>
```

Now test your connection (optional):

```
ping ubuntu.com -c 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!

Comment: This answer works, people. It was sad to find that after a lot of years not using Ubuntu Server most of the old ways of network configuration are not working. Hell, even the USB installer crashed two times on supported hardware ...

Comment: installing wpa_supplicant worked for me too - but it's disappointing that I had to plug in an ethernet cable to be able to install it. Come on Ubuntu, don't make me go searching for a long enough ethernet cable again!

Answer (score 2):

netplan is able configure but underlaying system fails. ubuntu server 20.04 dont include  wpasupplicant (which is only 1.4Mb), You should connect ethernet cable and restart then

```
apt install wpasupplicant
netplan apply
```

in 1 minutes it connects.